# Cannot find control with path: 'files -> 0 -> postId'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to create a dynamic form with formArray .

i click on the `AddItem` and must be create the input for upload file .

using this code in HTML :

```
    <div class="row m-auto col-md-12 pb-4">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
        <button (click)="AddItem()" mat-stroked-button color="warn">
            <i class="la la-plus"></i>
            <label class="pr-2 pl-2">
                ایجاد فایل جدید
            </label>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<div class="row m-auto col-md-12 pt-2">
    <form [formGroup]="uploadFormGroup">
        <div class="left row m-auto col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" formArrayName="files"
            *ngFor="let project of uploadFormGroup.get('files').controls; let i = index">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-sm-12">
                    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" formControlName="postId" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>{{ 'POST.FILE_TYPE' | translate }}</mat-label>
                        <mat-select>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of fileType | enumToArray" [value]="item">
                                {{ 'ENUM.FILE_TYPE.'+item | translate }}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-sm-5">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>{{ 'GENERAL.PHOTO' | translate }}</mat-label>
                        <mat-icon matSuffix>image</mat-icon>
                        <ngx-mat-file-input appearance="outline" formControlName="file" type=file
                            [placeholder]="'GENERAL.PHOTO' | translate">
                        </ngx-mat-file-input>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="row m-auto col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-lg-5 pb-4">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                        <button mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="removeItem(i)">حذف</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <button mat-flat-button color="primary">پیش نمایش</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                        <button mat-flat-button color="accent" (click)="Upload(i)">آپلود</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and this code in ts File :

```
  @Input() private postId: number;

  uploadFormGroup: FormGroup;
  fileType = TypeFile;
  fileUpload: FileUpload;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.uploadFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      postId: [''],
      files: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      typeEnum: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      file: ['']
    });
  }

  removeItem(index: number): void {
    const Item = <FormArray>this.uploadFormGroup.controls['files'];
    Item.removeAt(index);
  }

  AddItem(): void {
    const Item = <FormArray>this.uploadFormGroup.controls['files'];
    console.log(Item);
    Item.push(this.createItem());
  }

  Upload(fileId: number): void {

    this.fileUpload.postId = this.postId;
    this.fileUpload.typeEnum = this.uploadFormGroup.controls['typeEnum'].value;
    this.fileUpload.files = <FormArray>this.uploadFormGroup.controls['files'][fileId].value;
    this.postService.UplaodFile(this.fileUpload).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

now when i click on the `AddItem()` it show me this Error :

> Cannot find control with path: 'files -> 0 -> postId'

**Whats The Problem ????**

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code again
postId control is under uploadFormGroup not under files formArray and you are trying to access postId under files formArray

Either you have to add postId in files formArray or access it outside formArray loop in HTML

```
createItem(): FormGroup {
 return this.formBuilder.group({
  file: new FormControl(),
  postId: new FormControl()
 });
}
```

Comment: it now show me this `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'fileItems -> 1 -> typeEnum'`